# Find pattern in String C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Hi I have following string pattern:

`*A`

`*BA*`

`AB`

`*GN*BN`

I need to find such pattern in my input string.
If it matches, I need to replace the values accordingly.

How can I do it with regex?
Here pattern that I shown above is coming from XML file. So it is dynamic.
`*` here means wild card character. so,

`*A` means string ending with `A`.

`*BA*` means string containg `BA` in between.

`AB` means exact `AB` string.

Comment: Looks like homework. Use regexes (and google first).

Comment: @Filmzy The answer posted below. Not working.

Comment: Why would `BA` indicate contains but `AB` indicate an exact match?

Comment: @mlorbetske it is (start)BA(star) actually. Some how code formatting issue. AB is AB only.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to replace? Given `*AB`, do you _just_ want to replace the `AB` part? Given `*AB*CD` do you want to replace just `AB`, just `CD`, both, `AB*CD`, or what? What do you want to replace them _with_?

Comment: I think I used replace word at wrong place. In my case replace means, if I found this pattern in a given string, I will replace whole string with some other value. Like key value pair. So in dict, in key I will have like *A and if I found it in string, i will replace the whole string (say .N/A) with "NA" i.e. value of for the key *A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the patterns you're getting are pretty close to regexes already, just missing a `.` in front of the `*` to indicate that what can be repeated is 'anything' ([Repetition in regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

```
static bool PerformMatch(string rawPattern, string value)
{
    var adjustedPattern = rawPattern.Replace("*", ".*");
    var regex = new Regex(adjustedPattern);
    var match = regex.Match(value);
    return match.Success && match.Length == value.Length;
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(PerformMatch("*BA*", "Oh?"));  //false
    Console.WriteLine(PerformMatch("*BA*", "BAH!")); //true
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This works for some cases. Not all. Still good to know. thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which patterns are failing? Just tested all the ones you posted and they seem to be working appropriately, is there leading/trailing whitespace in the supplied values?

Answer (score 2):

The following function should fit your criteria.

```
public bool CustomMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    pattern = "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace(@"\*", ".*") + "$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
}
```

Comment: Hey, adding $ does not work. without it, it is working fine. Still one or two cases are failing in my case but will take care of it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `*` wildcard character indicate a single character or can it be multiple characters? Assuming single char. Also assumes that the 'wildcard character' is `[A-Z]` only

```
^(AB|^[A-Z]A|^[A-Z]BA[A-Z]|^[A-Z]GN[A-Z]BN)
```